# log4j debug not logging to any of the configured appenders

Tags: java, logging, log4j

`Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("CONSOLE")` returning null in a class but it can log to console. getAllAppenders() also returning NullEnumeration in this class.

In another class(MyClass) Logging level:DEBUG | Additivity:true | Parent:root | getAllAppenders():NullEnumeration
 but log.debug printing nothing to console.
 log4j configuration  for this class is

```
<logger name="com.xxx.service.impl.MyClass">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

tried to debug why is debug message not getting printed in many ways but in vain.

How can I check the log4j configuration for this class in depth and what could be the problem, please help me.

Comment: There is this parameter "-Dlog4j.debug=true". Add this and run it with it. It will say if there is any log4j property file on startup

Comment: @Neron thanks for your comment. I tried that option also.According to log4j debug log logger is taking my intended config file(log4j.xml) and all appenders are initialized properly(file appender with proper log file) and some classes can print logs to all appenders and some classes can't, MyClass as said above.I've added specific appender-ref for that MyClass logger also.Still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below listener in web.xml solved my problem.It configured my desired log4j.xml and log4j is logging fine.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- applies log4j configuration -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, u should set additivity parameter as false to be sure that each class is writing its logs to one log4j file:

log4j.additivity.${APPENDARNAME}=false

And make sure that only one log4j tech is loaded with your app(I prefer only log4j for basic staff)

Be sure that , no log4j.xml or log4j.properties files are under any of your classpath folders but the one that u want to be loaded. if that is a possiibility, force application to use yours. For spring:

```
<bean id="log4jInitializer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" >
    <property name="staticMethod">
        <value>org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>file:${log4jFile}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```